# updating one data.table from another data.table in R

Tags: r, join, data.table, left-join

im trying to update one table (bigDta, fields smiles) using data from another table, but it produces an error

```
    (bigData$smiles == '' | is.null(bigData$smiles) | is.na(bigData$smiles))
    & bigData$compound_id %in% tmpCompounds$compound_id
    ,
    `:=` (
      smiles=dtChembl[dtChembl$chembl_id == compound_id ,]$canonical_smiles
      , comment = paste(comment,'smiles added from chemblDB by chemblID;')
      , filteringStep=12
    ) 
  ]
```

the error i get is

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dtChembl, dtChembl$chembl_id == compound_id, ) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 5832210 but there are 1088555 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
In addition: Warning message:
In dtChembl$chembl_id == compound_id :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem..in case that anyone need it, this is solution:

```
  bigData[
    dtChembl
    , on=.(compound_id = chembl_id)
    ,
    `:=` (
      smiles= canonical_smiles
      , comment = paste(comment,'smiles added from chemblDB by chemblID;')
      , filteringStep=12
    ) 
  ]
```